# QUnit 2.0.1 + jQuery.trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I would like to hide error message when user starts typing into input field. The code is rather simple, but I would like to test it using QUnit 2.0.1 + jQuery.trigger method.

QUnit test doesn't pass, but the js script works properly when I test it manually. What is wrong with below code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-git.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture">
    <form>
        <input id="id_text" name="text"/>
        <div id="id_error">Error text</div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-git.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#id_text").on('keypress', function () { 
            $('#id_error').hide();
        });

        $("#id_text").on("click", function() {
            $("#id_error").hide();
        });

        QUnit.test("hide error on keypress", function (assert) {
            $('#id_text').trigger('keypress'); 
            assert.equal($('#id_error').is(':visible'), false);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like code inside `<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>` is not being recognized by the two functions.
So one thing you can do is move

```
    <input id="id_text" name="text"/>
    <div id="id_error">Error text</div>
```

out of `<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>`.
This works, but you might want to remember to initialize the input field for each test because it's out of the fixture-scope.

Another way is to move the two functions into `QUnit.test(){}` like this.

```
QUnit.test("hide error on keypress", function (assert) {

    $("#id_text").on('keypress', function () { 
        $('#id_error').hide();
    });

    $("#id_text").on("click", function() {
        $("#id_error").hide();
    });

    $("#id_text").trigger("click");
    assert.equal($('#id_error').is(':visible'), false);
});
```